# Minimal sufficient statistic for normal distribution with known variance

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from the $N(\theta,1)$ distribution. Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Now, I can find a sufficient statistic using the factorisation theorem ($\sum X_i$), but I don't think that this statistic is in fact minimal sufficient.

The question seems to imply that there exists a minimal sufficient statistic, but I'm not even sure that there is one.

MY QUESTION: How would I go about proving that there is no minimal sufficient statistic, or if there is one, what is it!?

Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $\theta\in \mathbb R$, this is a full rank (regular) exponential family. This makes $\sum X_i$ minimal sufficient. To show this directly, one can prove that the ratio $f_{\theta}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)/f_{\theta}(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ for $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\ne (y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ is free of $\theta$ if and only if $\sum x_i=\sum y_i$. [$f_{\theta}$ being the joint pdf]

Answer (score 2):

By the factorization criterion
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\{-\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2/2 +\bar{X}_n \theta -n\theta^2/2\} 
$$
$$
  \qquad = \exp\{\bar{X}_n\theta-n\theta^2/2\}\times(2\pi)^{-n/2}\exp\{-\sum X_i^2/2\}.
$$
So $\bar{X}_n$ is sufficient statistic.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is it always true that if the dimension of a sufficient statistic $T$ is the same as that of the parameter space, then $T$ is minimal sufficient?

Comment: @V.Vancak [I don't think your comment is correct](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503933/if-the-dimension-of-a-sufficient-statistic-tx-equals-the-dimension-of-parame).

Comment: @Tan Ok, deleted the comment. However, note the context. The sufficient stat in the answer was derived from the factorization criteria. Hence, this is have to be true. $(\bar{x}, sign(x_1)s)$ is not a counterexample as this is, as stated in the link, not a one-to-one function of the MSS found, e.g., using the factorization criteria.

Comment: @V.Vancak Thanks for your reply. However, I am not sure what do you mean by "MSS found by factorization criteria". If by "factorization criteria" you mean factorization theorem, I don't think I agree with you. A statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient for $\theta$ is equivalent to say $T(X)$ factorizes the pdf as $\delta(T(X),\theta)h(X)$. Since $(\bar{x},\text{sgn}(x_1)s)$ is sufficient for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, it must satisfy the factorization theorem. Actually, many people use factorization theorem as the definition of a sufficient statistic.

Comment: @Tan By "factorization criteria" I mean factorization criterion. You may refer to it as factorization theorem, if you wish so. Anyway, OK. I've deleted the comment about it being minimal (nonetheless, it is indeed minimal, but it needs to be proved).

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient statistic $Y$ is a function of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ for which the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $Y$ does not depend on $\theta.$ Implicit in this is that one need not know the value of $\theta$ in order to know which function of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is $Y.$

A sufficient statistic $Y$ is minimal if for every function $g$ that is not one-to-one, and whose domain is the support of the random variable $Y,$ the random variable $g(Y)$ is not sufficient. I.e. no coarser statistic is sufficient.

A coarser statistic than $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ must have equal values for two different values of $X_1+\cdots+X_n.$ Suppose that for $X_1+\cdots+X_n=a$ and $X_1+\cdots+X_n=b,$ we have the same value of $Y,$ say $Y=c,$ although $a\ne b.$

Consider the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $Y=c.$ What is that distribution when $\theta=a/n,$ and what is it when $\theta=b/n$? You get two different distributions; therefore $Y$ is not sufficient.